# "hello world" crashes eclipse debug mode

Tags: eclipse, debugging

Eclipse works fine in run mode, but it crashes in debug mode, no matter what. Everything was fine a minute ago and I didn't make any updates or so prior to the occurrence of this error.

What do I need to do to go back to business as usual?

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBiX4.png)

Comment: Try starting Eclipse with the -clean option. If that doesn't work, create a new project and if that doesn't work, try a new install of Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Problem got fixed by updating eclipse, JDK, and JRE.